# Edittext long press menu color

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-holo-everywhere

I am using the library holoeverywhere.
The problem I have is when I select a word from EditText, the menu that appears does not look good. Below have a picture to better illustrate what happens.

[image]

How I can fix that?
Here the code of my xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/base"
    >


    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:text="Crear Usuario"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
        android:shadowRadius="1.5"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="2"
        android:id="@+id/btSeccion"
        android:background="#0e0101"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Escriba su nombre de usuario:"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="#7F6000"
        android:id="@+id/tvEscriba"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        />


    <LinearLayout  android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0e0101"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="100"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:id="@+id/etNombreUsuario"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Nombre de Usuario"
            android:cursorVisible="true"
            android:maxLength="25"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textCapWords"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:singleLine="true"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/wbantes"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
        android:background="#0e0101"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Antes de empezar a adentrarnos en el fascinante mundo de la lectura rápida, necesitamos saber cuál es su velocidad actual de lectura comprensiva. Para ello le voy a pedir que escriba su nombre de usuario, lo cual le permitirá realizar el test inicial, fundamental para saber de qué nivel partimos."
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="#0e0101"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="1dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you used a custom layout for the popup ? @Oscar Mendez

Comment: no, i'm not. I edit the question with my entire xml file.

Comment: How are you bringing up the dialog? That is important.

Comment: @JoxTraex I bringing up with long press on the edittext, to paste or copy content.

Comment: Post code for long press with Dialog code.

Comment: that dialog is for default for all edittext.